# Visual Studio 2010, solution with a form and web service

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with a form and web service and want to debug the web service. I've tried set the .asmx page as the start page. I guess it's more of a Visual Studio 2010 question rather than a vb question.

Comment: Does your form invoke the web service?  If so, you should just be able to put a breakpoint in the web service code and execute the code that calls the service.

Comment: If you're using IIS to host the web service, then you can attach to the relevant wpw3 worker process and then your breakpoints will be hit.

Comment: why not simply use `msgbox` to display all the information you need to debug?that's the best way to debug if you are a beginner

Comment: @DeanOC I'm running it locally for testing purposes. I put breakpoints in, and I attached it to my webserver process (it wasn't called wpw3), but the breakpoints were never hit even though they should have been.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: So where is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that my application's settings were still pointing to the production web service. I changed them to point to the local service which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

just type in the complete webservice url in the browser. You will be able to provide the paramets value and run the webservice.
eg of a url: `localhost:53788/HelloWorld.asmx.`

Comment: That will only work for basic parameters like strings, ints & dates. It won't work if the webmethod requires an instantiated class object.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem could be that you haven't enabled debugging in your **web.config** file. Your config file needs to look like this.

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.web>
        <compilation
            debug="true"
            ...
        >
        ...
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

See here for more information. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx